# Why use rbegin() instead of end() - 1?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, reverse-iterator

I'm wondering what the benefits of using rbegin() rather than end() - 1 are for STL containers.

For example, why would you use something like:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(999);
vector<int>::reverse_iterator r = v.rbegin();
vector<int>::iterator i = r.base();
```

Rather than:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(999);
auto r = v.end() - 1;
```

Comment: Think about `<algorithm>` , such as `std::for_each(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), worker);`.

Comment: any reason you used `auto` in second example?

Comment: @ UnKnown Just to type fewer characters.

Comment: @VictorBrunell So you shortened it to make it look simpler and better than `rbegin` :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`rbegin()` return an iterator with a *reverse* `operator++`; that is, with a `reverse_iterator` you can iterate through a container going backward.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4};
    for( auto i = v.rbegin(); i != v.rend(); ++i )
        std::cout << *i << '\n';
}
```

Furthermore, some standard containers like `std::forward_list`, return *forward iterators*, so you wouldn't be able to do `l.end()-1`.

Finally, if you have to pass your iterator to some algorithm like `std::for_each` that presuppose the use of the `operator++`, you are forced to use a `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: I was thinking of iterating backwards using itr-- rather than itr++ to go in reverse, but using the built-in functionality makes more sense I guess.  Thanks.

Comment: @VictorBrunell Updated my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks.  That's very helpful.

Answer (score 20):

If the container is empty, `end() - 1` will not be defined.

Comment: So, for a one element vector, begin() and rbegin() point to the same element?  I see.  Thanks.

Comment: @VictorBrunell: Yes and no. Forward iterators and reverse iterators are not compatible. You cannot do `v.begin() == v.rbegin()`. But you can compare the elements they point to, i.e. `&*(v.begin()) == &*(v.rbegin())` is defined and will be true for a 1-element vector.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: well, for one element vector, `end() - 1` is defined though. @VictorBrunell