# What is the difference between begin () and rend ()?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I have a question in iterators about the difference between `begin()` and `rend()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1;
    v1 = {9,2,6,4,5};
    cout<<*v1.begin();
    cout<<*v1.rend();
    return 0;
}
```

`cout<<*v1.begin();`
returns 9

but
`cout<<*v1.rend();`
returns a number that is not 9

Why are there such different results?

Comment: `rend().base() == begin()`.

Comment: [`rend()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend) returns "past-the-end" iterator, just like `end()` does. Dereferencing it is Undefined Behaviour. (well, `rend()` is more of "before-the-begin", but you get the idea).

Comment: `rend` is the reverse iterator the end (begin of original vector) and  begin is the iterator to the begin

Comment: Here is a related question: [Why use rbegin() instead of end() - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208657/why-use-rbegin-instead-of-end-1)

Comment: `v1.begin() <=> --v1.rend()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does"one-past-the-last-element" mean in vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34830192/what-doesone-past-the-last-element-mean-in-vectors)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, ranges are marked by a pair of iterators marking the beginning of the range and a position one past the end of the range. For containers, the `begin()` and `end()` member functions provide you with a pair of iterators to the first and past-the-end positions. It’s not safe to read from `end()`, since it doesn’t point to an actual element.

Similarly, the `rbegin()` and `rend()` member functions return reverse iterators that point, respectively, to the last and just-before-the-first positions. For the same reason that it’s not safe to dereference the `end()` iterator (it’s past the end of the range), you shouldn’t dereference the `rend()` iterator, since it doesn’t point to an element within the container.

Answer (score 7):

Dereferencing `end()` or `rend()` has undefined behaviour.

`begin()` points to the first element, `rbegin()` points to the last element. `end()` (in most cases) points to one after the last element and `rend()` effectively points to one before the first element (though it isn't implemented like that).

Comment: It is "one past the end" so your loop can end on the condition `it == end()` (or `rend()` of course) and get every element in the range. (In a loop of course the end condition is the _negative_ of what you want so it is written `it != end()` but that's obvious.)

Comment: _"though it isn't implemented like that"_ Why not?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit doesn't apply to all containers, but for example you cannot use pointer arithmetic to get address of the element before the first one of array like you can get the one past the last, can you?

Comment: @eerorika Oh yeah :D

Answer (score 5):

> What is the difference between `begin ()` and `rend ()`?

`begin` returns an **iterator** to the **first element** of the container.

`rend` returns a **reverse iterator** to **one before the first element** of the container (which is one past the last element in the reverse iterator range).

> ```
> *v1.rend()
> ```

The behaviour of indirecting through the `rend` iterator is undefined (same goes for indirecting through `end` iterator).

> Why are there such different results?

Besides behaviour being undefined in one case and not the other, since they refer to different to different elements (one of them being an element that doesn't exist), there is little reason to assume the results to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

`vector::rend()` is a built-in function in the C++ standard library which returns a reverse iterator pointing to the theoretical element right before the first element in the array container. but `vector::begin()` returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the vector.

See this code :

```
for (auto it = v1.rbegin(); it != v1.rend(); it++) 
    cout << *it << " ";
```

The vector elements in reverse order are :

```
5 4 6 2 9
```

To iterate in the vector always choose one of these methods together :

- `vector::begin()` and `vector::end()`
- `vector::cbegin()` and `vector::cend()`
- `vector::crbegin()` and `vector::crend()`
- `vector::rbegin()` and `vector::rend()`

For more information see ["C++ Vector Tutorial With Example" by Ankit Lathiya](https://appdividend.com/2019/05/03/cpp-vector-tutorial-with-example-vector-in-cpp-stl/).

*[Try it online](http://cpp.sh/32hji)*

Comment: Some weird stuff going on in that linked article. Like: _"The vector:: assign() is an STL in C++"_ o.O