# Reverse Iterator not working as expected C++

Tags: c++

Hey i was wondering why this code doesnt give 1 to output.

```
    vector<int> myVector{1, 2, 3, 4, 6};
    cout << *myVector.rend() << endl;
```

Output should be 1 but it gives random numbers.

But in this example everything is okay.

```
    vector<int> myVector{1, 2, 3, 4, 6};
    cout << *myVector.rbegin() << endl;
```

Output : 6

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between begin () and rend ()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612556/what-is-the-difference-between-begin-and-rend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`end()` points to the memory location ***after*** the last element. Similarly, `rend()` points to memory location ***before*** the first element. They are supposed to be used as sentinel values ─ i.e. to iterate until that point is reached.
So, to print 1, you should use:

```
cout << *(myVector.rend()-1) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

"end" iterators are really "past the end" and not dereferencable, no matter whether they're forward or reverse.

BTW: Enable diagnostic mode for you C++ stdlib. It would have told you something's wrong. How you do that depends on the compiler and stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that `end()` gives an invalid iterator "one item after the range", `rend()` gives an invalid iterator "one item before the range". So your first example outputs whatever semi-random data happens to be at that place in memory.